# iphone webservice

Tags: iphone

How to invoke a webservice request as a XMLHttpRequest in iphone

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Depends on where you want to do it. If you're viewing content in a UIWebView you have two ways depending on if you need access to the return value in the Objective-C bit. You can call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString from Objective-C to execute any piece of JavaScript code.

Alternatively if you are working completely in HTML and JavaScript with little interaction with Objective-C, you may use it like you would on any webpage. I'd recommend using Jquery's AJAX functionality however.